# how do I create a multidimensional associative array inside of a foreach loop?

Tags: php

I want to create an array that looks like this

```
 $appsByOs = Array(
                  osName1 =>Array(0=>app1,1=>app2)
                  osName2 =>Array(0=>app1,1=>app2)
                  etc.....
  )
```

how could i do this inside of a foreach loop?

```
  foreach($osInstanceNames as $osInstanceName){
                    $appNames(array of app names for current os)

            }
```

thanks

Comment: Could you please clarify what you wanted created dynamically. was it creating $appsByOs dynamically whne you already have a method of populating $appNames. If it was $appNames can you please give us some clue of the data source for $appNames

Comment: it was creating $appsByOs dynamically. $appNames is already populated by a query that is run according to each osInstanceName.

Comment: My answer below creates $appsByOs dynamically populating a osName key with the current osName and assigning whatever value you have in $appNames. what it does not do is populate $appNames with different data for each OS. You would need to call a function to get different data into $appNames for each OS though as otherwise each os will have the same apps listed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you should need to do is this.

```
 $appsByOs = Array();
 foreach($osInstanceNames as $osInstanceName){
                     $appsByOs[$osInstanceName] = $appNames;

 }
```

Comment: It was a typo that was removed

Comment: Almost but not quite Anigel, what happens when a second app is added to the array? At the moment you will overwrite the previous app with this code.

Comment: If by app you mean appNames then this was specified as being an array in the question rather than being needed to be looped over

Comment: Indeed, but you've not understood what I was saying. `$appNames` in your code will overwrite any previous assignment to `$appsByOs[$osInstanceName]`. Ouput will only ever have the last AppName assigned to it by the loop, not an array of AppNames.

Comment: Sorry Anigel, I shoulda learned to read the question! You are correct. Though I think that he actually wants the array created dynamically...

Comment: I thought he wanted $appsByOs created dynamically not $appNames. We would need more data to be able to show how to create $appNames as we have no information regarding data sources. I have asked OP to clarify.

Comment: yes I would like the array created dynamically. with each iteration through the foreach loop it should create another key by the name of the os with an array as the value with the apps specified in the appNames array. at the end I should have a large multidimensional array full of all of the os names and their values being an array of each os' respective apps.

Comment: this will work because the $appNames var is already an array therefore each osInstanceName will only have to add one $appNames to it.

Answer (score 0):

Recovering the last post and adding the possibility to have more than one app for an os instance

```
 $appsByOs = Array(); 
 foreach($osInstanceNames as $osInstanceName){ 
                     $appsByOs[$osInstanceName][] = $appNames; 

 }
```

Comment: This would not answer the question. this would lead to output of osName1 =>Array(0=>array(app1),1=>array(app2)) The question shows $appNames as already being an array and also relies on each os being listed multiple times in $osInstanceNames